# Single Selection Menu Item Strange Behavior

Tags: android, menu, selection, menuitem

I recently had a problem with menu items, and asked a question here - [Group menu items work but don't display checkmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471846/group-menu-items-work-but-dont-display-checkmark/30481736#30481736).

I figured out the problem; however, I noticed a strange behavior with single-selection radio button `menu items`.

I know you have to set the checked state of a selectable menu item

> Menu items in the Icon Menu (from the options menu) cannot display a checkbox or radio button. If you choose to make items in the Icon Menu checkable, you must manually indicate the checked state by swapping the icon and/or text each time the state changes.

However, it does not matter if you set it to `true` or `false`. Both provide a `radio button`-like check state that you would expect.

### Example

```
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.mode_sign :
            item.setChecked(true);
            display = BinaryOperation.Display.SIGN;
            return true;

        case R.id.mode_verb :
            item.setChecked(true);
            display = BinaryOperation.Display.VERB;
            return true;

        case R.id.mode_noun :
            item.setChecked(true);
            display = BinaryOperation.Display.NOUN;
            return true;

        default : return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

The above code has the exact same behavior if you swap the `item.setChecked(true)` to `item.setChecked(false)`. As expected, if you remove the `setChecked()` statements, then no `menu item` will be selected.

**So** how does the process of menu item selection actually work?  And why does setting `true` or `false` not matter?

Comment: Did you try to invalidate the actionbar?? 


Like this:
activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();

Comment: Why would I need to do that? Why recreate the whole menu?

Comment: Because you need redraw the actionbar, so you can see the change.

Is more like a guess.

Did you try it?

Comment: Everything works in my code. I am wondering why setting `item.setChecked (false)` causes the `item` to show a check. It makes sense for `true` to show the check but why `false`?